# Cannot find module reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am new to react I am trying added new component called Test and try to use it the app.js imported test into app.js but still get error. Below you can find stackblitz url Thanks in Advance.

[Stackblitz url](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cxszsx?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: Have you tried to change path to this: `./components/test`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue in your sandbox is `Components` whereas your folder name is `components`:

```
import Test from  './Components';
```

and you need to complete file path if your not using `index.js` as reference i.e

```
import Test from  './components/Test';
```

Here is demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vcw5a8?file=src%2FApp.js

Answer (score 4):

`import Test from './components/test'`

Implement this line, make sure that `c` is written in lowercase in `component/...` path OR just copy the line above and replace yours with it. That will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to go here: Either you import the File directly like this:

```js
import Test from  './components/Test';
```

or you create a `index.js`within the `Components`-Folder and add this:

```js
import Test from './test.jsx';

export default Test;
```

Also, your Import-Statments are Upper-Case whereas you folder-name is lowercase, so you'll have to adjust on or the other.